# get-task-allowed remains true when developer signed binary is resigned as distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I want a flow where my project is set up to produce an application signed with the development mobile provisioning profile, that can be resigned for AdHoc or AppStore distribution later on using Xcode's convenient interface for this.

The problem is that when I create an archive signed by a development provisioning profile, both the `embedded.mobileprovision` and the application binary itself contain the specification `get-task-allowed` set to `true`, but when I re-sign that application using Xcode's UI for this, the result is an application where `embedded.mobileprovision` has `get-task-allowed` set to `false` (as I want), but the binary itself still contains `get-task-allowed` set to `true` (not what I want).

So how do I resign the application properly so that my distribution profile used for re-signing gets properly applied throughout the resulting application?

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4.2 does just as you want, ie you can archive using a developer profile and then resign during organiser -> share with a distribution profile.  As long as both profiles were for the same app id it would result in proper output (get-task-allow is set to false for both the runtime binary and embedded.mobileprovision files)

XCode 4.3 however does not do the same, I have performed the same steps with the same certificates and profiles and the resulting output if get-task-allow=false in embedded.mobileprovision BUT get-task-allow=true in the runtime binary.  The IPA will then fail to sync with a device and the console output will spit out something along the lines of "get-task-allow has value not permitted"

I am currently downloading 4.4 (it came out yesterday) so I'll be running another set of tests on that version.

Comment: I have since worked out that you can make this flow work on iOS >= 4.3 by manually adding an entitlements file yourself and setting get-task-allow to NO